# Left Join Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to go a little deeper into Eloquent ORM relationships and can't get my head around doing this:

```php
$a = new Attachments();
$tmp = $a->where( 'attached_to', ATTACHMENTS::ATTACHED_TO_TASK )
           ->where( 'db_id', $task_id )
           ->select( 'db_id', 'user_id', 'attachments.id', 'real_filename', DB::raw( "concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as uploader" ) )
           ->leftJoin( 'users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_id' )
           ->get();
```

I've got this far:

```php
$tmp=Tasks::find($task_id)->attachments->where('attached_to',ATTACHMENTS::ATTACHED_TO_TASK);
```

... and I can live without the concat, but I can't figure out for the life of me the syntax to get details from the users table in the same statement.

Tasks have many attachments. Attachments from many users belong to one task. Attachments belong to one user.

Answer (score 1):

If your relations are well established in the models and the tables have the correct fields following the Laravel Naming Conventions, then:

`attachments` table have these fields: `user_id` , `task_id`.

With this:

`$tasks = Tasks::with('attachments')->where('id', $task->id)->get();`

In a blade view do a foreach:
`@foreach($tasks as $task)`

and `$tasks->attachments->user` should give you all the user data.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'm curious if under the hood that foreach..$tasks->attachments->user will result in an additional query for each attachment?

Comment: Sorry, missed on last comment - this doesn't take into account the attachments.attached_to where clause. I don't need the task data (already have it), just attachments where attachments.task_id=$task_id, attached_to=X and join the users table on attachments.user_id=$user_id

Comment: what are you storing in attached_to?

Comment: Same attachments table is used for attachments to tasks & processes, so in this case where attached_to='task'. Hence in class Tasks I have function attachments() as a hasMany to Attachments::class with foreign key db_id.

Comment: Have you tried to use a simple join. Replace ` ->leftJoin( 'users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_id' )` with ` ->join( 'users', 'users.id', 'user_id' )`. I'm curious, process is another table that have attachments and owners same as tasks?

Comment: The original query works fine - I'm just trying to do the same thing with relationships and can't figure out the joining part in a single query :)

Comment: This seems to be getting closer:
`Attachments::with('user')->where('db_id',$task_id)->where('attached_to',ATTACHMENTS::ATTACHED_TO_TASK)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to something @Thomas said I came to a solution thus:

```php
Attachments::with('user')
->where('db_id',$task_id)
->where('attached_to','task')
->get();
```

with a relationship defined in Attachments::class as

```php
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```